# find min(a,b,c) or max(a,b,c) with using #define macro preprocessor in c

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

this is the question what asked in my exam is: "write cource code of min(a,b,c) with macros in c language."

```
#define min(a,b,c) ((a)<(b)?((a)<(c)?(a):(c)):((b)<(c)?(b):(c)))
```

is there better way to solve min/max(x,y,z) problem?

Comment: Yes - not using macros.

Comment: Note that with FP numbers employing [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), this will not return the expected answer for `min(1.0, NaN, NaN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key point you missed in the question is "macros" not and macro. You can simplify this a lot if you break it down further as follows -

```
#define min2(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define min(a, b, c) (min2(min2((a), (b)), (c)))
```

This is also much easier to comprehend.

Comment: Typical good macro guidelines employ `()` around each argument usage.  `(min2(min2(a, b), (c)))` --> `(min2(min2((a), (b)), (c)))`

Comment: @chux Yes, but since `min2` already has the brackets, I did not add it to `min`. You can see I added it around `c` though.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution, and all portable macro-based ones, are a good reason why the use of macros should be limited as much as possible. Nowadays, I pretty much use them for little more than conditional compilation.

In terms of defining constants, you are better off with enumerations.

In terms of function-like macros, you're far better off using functions which you can suggest to the compiler to be made inline, or just rely on the compiler to figure that out (they're usually pretty good at that).

---

The reason why function-like macros are a bad idea is because, being simple text substitution, the sequence:

```
#define mymax(a, b) (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b)
int x = mymax(y++, complexFunction());
```

will actually evaluate `y++` and/or call `complexFunction()` *more than once,* something a real function would not do.

By all means use them provided you understand the limitations. Me, I'll rely on the compiler doing the right thing for functions so that I don't have to worry about the dark corners of C too much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Write functions.

```
int min2( int x, int y        ) { return x < y ? x : y; }
int min3( int x, int y, int z ) { return min2( x, min2( y, z ) ); }
```

If you wish for pretty, you can write some variadic macros that choose the correct function based on the number of arguments. Those are a bear to write, though.

If you wish to stick with *only* macros, your choices are much less friendly. **Ajay B**’s solution (fixed as per commentary) works well.

GCC supports some [nice extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) that eliminate re-evaluation issues:

```
#define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

You can then easily write any n-ary macro you wish that does not suffer from parenthetical or re-evaluation horrors.

```
#define max3(a,b,c) max(a,max(b,c))
```

Comment: As per my understanding, the compiler should usually take care of the re-evaluation issues, unless of course the variables are explicitly marked as `volatile`.

Comment: You have been taught wrong. Consider: `max( ++x, y )`. What happens to x?